# Mass Rename Files including sub directories

Tags: linux, centos, rename, bulk

I have many file having "example.com" in them and I want to replace it with "example.co" as i change my site tld, i have rename program installed in my server and have root access too.

Can anybody help me in renaming it.

Sample location of files:

```
/var/html/downloads/folder1/folder1-1/abc(example.com).mp4
/var/html/downloads/folder2/folder2-1/abc(example.com).mp4
/var/html/downloads/folder2/folder2-2/abc(example.com).mp4
/var/html/downloads/folder3/folder3-1/abc(example.com).mp4
```

I hope some1 will help me out here :)

PS: I used this cmd but got below error:

```
cmd: find -name "*example*" | xargs -I '{}' rename s/com/co/ '{}'
```

Error:

```
For more details see rename(1).
rename: not enough arguments

Usage:
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

Comment: There's two "standard" versions of Linux rename, a newer one that expects Perl regular expressions and yours which I think is modeled after an older Unix version which accepts two parameters for search and replacement. Try `xargs -I '{}' rename "com" "co" '{}'` . Though that might be overly broad as it will catch any instance of "com". If Perl is installed you can probably use `prename` as the regex version you're thinking of instead.

Comment: Your sample file names don't contain "example.com" in the file name, are you trying to replace text within the content of the files? In that case you'll want to use the `sed` command instead of `rename` .

Comment: Your question is conflicted.  You say you need to change example.com *within* the files, but then give an example to change the filenames.  Then to top it off, you give example filenames that are neither related to example.com in any way, and are binary .mp4 files.  It is not something is wrong here, everything is wrong.  There is no answer to this question.

Comment: A properly designed website will contain relative links within the html files so that this problem is avoided entirely.  Are you sure there are fqdn's coded into the html?  Or is this a guess?

Comment: Looking at the usage text, I am sure @baochan is correct about your version of `rename`. Three points: (1) the script will fail if there are embedded blanks (you need to use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`); (2) using `xargs -I` runs a separate `rename` for each file found - it's much more efficient simply to pipe to `xargs -0 rename com co`, which runs `rename` just once, with all the files in its run string; (3) to run `rename` once per file you needn't use `xargs` at all - use `find -name "*example*" -exec rename com co '{}' \;`